# global serverless functions callable at specific locations

Tags: service-worker, serverless, deno, cloudflare-workers, faas

Is there a service like Deno Deploy or Cloudflare Workers that auto-deploys functions to many locations around the globe **and** lets developers address/call them at specific locations (not just let users reach the closest location)?

This would immediately obsolete a whole range of paid monitoring services and let many people write better replacements.

Answer (score 2):

Macrometa provides serverless computing (currently in beta) that allows developers to call in two ways i.e., using a global URL (which does automatic geo-routing)  or using directly the URL of a compute instance in a specific location. (Disclaimer: I work at Macrometa).

Regards,
Durga